# My buildozer suddenly reject to turn my kivy app into android apk ;(

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm making a kivy app that works on android smartphone. It colaborates with sqlite3. But as I try to transport as a android apk using my buildozer, suddenly my buildozer denied to work. The Error message is this.

```
[DEBUG]:   -> running mv sqlite-amalgamation-3350500 /mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3
[DEBUG]:        /usr/bin/mv: cannot move 'sqlite-amalgamation-3350500' to '/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3': Permission denied
Exception in thread background thread for pid 463:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/mv sqlite-amalgamation-3350500 /mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3

  STDOUT:
/usr/bin/mv: cannot move 'sqlite-amalgamation-3350500' to '/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3': Permission denied


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1297, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 730, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 491, in build_recipes
    recipe.prepare_build_dir(arch.arch)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 587, in prepare_build_dir
    self.unpack(arch)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 461, in unpack
    shprint(sh.mv, root_directory, directory_name)
  File "/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/leejieung/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/mv sqlite-amalgamation-3350500 /mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3

  STDOUT:
/usr/bin/mv: cannot move 'sqlite-amalgamation-3350500' to '/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sqlite3': Permission denied


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=LingoAdventure --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     WT_SESSION = '3eb1ebcd-3650-44c7-983c-054f1eff6565'
#     NAME = 'LeeJE-Laptop'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/KivyApk/Lingo_Chans'
#     LOGNAME = 'leejieung'
#     HOME = '/home/leejieung'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/43_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'leejieung'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir'
#     WSLENV = 'WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/leejieung/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/leejieung/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/windows/system32:/mnt/c/windows:/mnt/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA '
 'Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server '
 '8.0/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/PowerShell/7/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/Users/lje64/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/lje64/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/lje64/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/lje64/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS Code/bin:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     PULSE_SERVER = '/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
#     WT_PROFILE_ID = '{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}'
#     _ = '/home/leejieung/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/leejieung/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/leejieung/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/leejieung/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

What's the problem? Please tell me the solution as quick as possible...

I searched into whole internet but I cannot find any clues

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- Try to run buildozer with sudo
- Change your project directory to your /usr/ location. Maybe the permission error is a result of your /mnt/c/ folder.

If you want to publish the app in the appstore you have to raise the API to 31.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The ultimal-fundamental problem was "A Vaccine program's prohibition"! I have 'AhnLab V3' vaccine program and it disturbed my buildozer from working. Anyway thank you